# Angular formatDate() setting my value to previous value

Tags: javascript, angular, formatdatetime

I have the block of code below and 'deathDate' gets a correct value, but then 'dateOfLastWages' is null and formatDate() sets  'this.matterData.dateOfLastWages' to 'this.matterData.deathDate'

```js
this.matterService.getMatterData(this.claim.matter.matterNumber)
  .subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.matterData = res;
      this.matterData.birthDate = formatDate(res.birthDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'en-US');
      this.matterData.deathDate = formatDate(res.deathDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'en-US');
      this.matterData.dateOfLastWages = formatDate(res.dateOfLastWages, 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'en-US');
      this.loading = false;
    }, error => {
      this.alertService.error(error);
    },
    () => {

    }
  );
```

Comment: Are you sure the Observable is returning the correct data? If `res.dateOfLastWages` is null, that is probably due to incomplete data being returned by your `getMatterData()` method.

Comment: yes, it's correctly being returned. I fixed it by checking if the value is null first and only calling the formateDate if it's not null. Maybe there is some issue with formateDate()?

Comment: What format is res.birthDate/deathDate/etc. in?

Comment: They are strings like: "1938-08-08T00:00:00"